# Can Torch optim package support multiple inputs

Tags: optimization, lua, neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I'm trying to use the torch7 [optim package adam algorithm implementation](https://github.com/torch/optim/blob/master/adam.lua)
for optimizing a neural network which takes two independent inputs. Can this be done? The code seems to only support a single input vector. Is there some other implementation which can take a generic table of inputs?
The reference usage I saw, upon which I based my code is [here](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style/blob/master/neural_style.lua)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, if you flatten all your parameters and gradients into two tensors then optim can handle it. See [getParameters()](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/Module.lua#L285) function.